# making css button:hover animation work

Tags: html, css

I am expecting the following code to animate button on hover.
But this is not working properly -

```
#button3 { 
    float: left; 
    height: 200px; 
    width: 200px;
}
#button3:hover {        
    animation: 3s stilius forwards;
    -webkit-transition: 3s stilius forwards;}
@keyframes stilius {
    100% {border-style: dashed;}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define an initial state for the border otherwise it won't know how to transition.

For example:

```
#button3 {
  border-style:solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color:#000;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#button3:hover {
  animation: 3s stilius forwards;
  -webkit-transition: 3s stilius forwards;
}

@keyframes stilius {
  100% {
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: dashed;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the border property?
You have to add the border property first to animate it

```
eg:border:5px solid;
```

If thats not the problem, If you are using browser like mozilla etc use the -moz- and -o- prefixes as well